# Executable file does not exist after compiling Fortran code

Tags: linux, cmake, fortran

I am compiling using cmake. I am on Linux with an intel processor. The important cmake lines are

```
set(SRCS srcA.FOR srcB.FOR ... srcK.FOR)
add_executable(filename ${SRCS})
```

I get no errors, just warnings. There are three types of warnings:

1. I am not using a variable (bad on my part but surely not code-breaking)
2. "this name has not been given a specific type"
3. "no action performed for file 'path/to/file/filename.FOR.o'"

Right before the "no action..." warning it says

`Linking Fortran executable filename`

and the last line says

`Built target filename`

That last line in particular to me implies that there should be an executable file, but I cannot find it. I have tried searching for it using
`find -type f -name "*.exe"` and `find -type f -name "*filename*" and neither are returning anything.

I will note that I am new to compiling these types of files on Linux, so I am sure there is something small I am doing wrong and don't know what it is

**EDIT** Added more detailed error output
Note that the "no action performed..." error appears once for each file and is identical (besides the filename of course)

```
ifort: warning #10145: no action performed for file 'CMakeFiles/dynamicmpm.dir/getversion.for.o'
```

**EDIT #2** Adding the contents of the cmake file below

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(MPM)

enable_language (Fortran)

get_filename_component (Fortran_COMPILER_NAME ${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER} NAME)

MESSAGE("Fortran_COMPILER_NAME = ${Fortran_COMPILER_NAME}")


set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "-nologo -O2 -assume buffered_io -fpp -Dinternal_release -reentrancy threaded -free -warn all -real_size 64 -Qauto -fp:strict -fp:constant -libs:static -threads -Qmkl:sequential -c -Qm64") 


if (Fortran_COMPILER_NAME MATCHES "gfortran")
  # gfortran
  set(COMMON_FLAGS "-fmax-identifier-length=63 -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none -fdefault-real-8")
  set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE} ${COMMON_FLAGS}")
  set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG   "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG} ${COMMON_FLAGS}")
endif()

set(SRCS srcA.FOR srcB.FOR ... srcK.FOR) #theres a bazillion files so I made this dummy line for the post
add_executable(filename ${SRCS})
```

**EDIT 3**

I get the following error now after making the changes recommended below:

```
[100%] Linking Fortran executable dynamicmpm
CMakeFiles/dynamicmpm.dir/Solver.FOR.o: In function `modsolver_mp_createprofiledss_':
Solver.FOR:(.text+0x1143): undefined reference to `dss_create_'
Solver.FOR:(.text+0x11a8): undefined reference to `dss_define_structure_'
Solver.FOR:(.text+0x1471): undefined reference to `dss_reorder_'
CMakeFiles/dynamicmpm.dir/Solver.FOR.o: In function `modsolver_mp_solveequations_':
Solver.FOR:(.text+0x35ec): undefined reference to `dss_factor_real_d__'
Solver.FOR:(.text+0x361d): undefined reference to `dss_solve_real_d_'
CMakeFiles/dynamicmpm.dir/Solver.FOR.o: In function `modsolver_mp_destroyequations_':
Solver.FOR:(.text+0x4495): undefined reference to `dss_delete_'
CMakeFiles/dynamicmpm.dir/Solver.FOR.o: In function `modsolver_mp_initialisereducedsolution_':
Solver.FOR:(.text+0x5a58): undefined reference to `dss_create_'
Solver.FOR:(.text+0x5abd): undefined reference to `dss_define_structure_'
Solver.FOR:(.text+0x606d): undefined reference to `dss_reorder_'
```

at the top of Solver.FOR I have `use mkl_dss` and mkl_dss.f90 is included in
`set(SRCS srcA.FOR srcB.for mkl_dss.f90 ... otherSources.FOR)`

Am I linking the files incorrectly?

Comment: Searching for `*.exe` on Linux has a little sense: Unlike to Windows, on Linux an executable has no `.exe` extension.

Comment: "I am not using a variable (bad on my part but surely not code-breaking)" - fix the problem and build the project again. "this name has not been given a specific type", "no action performed for file 'path/to/file/filename.FOR.o'" - Please, copy paste the **exact** output into the question post. You may format the output as a code, using `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button. Usually, putting exact output into the question post is much more informative than *describing* that output.

Comment: I added the no action error messages above and am working on the unused variable ones as well. I should have mentioned that the code DOES compile fine on Windows, but I am trying to get it to build on Linux as well. This leads me to believe the issue is how I am linking the files, NOT in the code itself. My fault for not mentioning that sooner.

Comment: It is odd you are getting filename.for.o, most builds use filename.o. Did you do a lot of cmake changes? We might need to see more of your cmake file

Comment: @Cocofalco what in the cmake file would cause that? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I added the contents of the cmake file @Cocofalco

Answer (score 1):

`no action performed for file 'path/to/file/filename.FOR.o'` - You passed `-c` to flags, so compiler does not know what to do with object files. Research what `-c` flag means. Remove `-c` flag.

`get_filename_component (Fortran_COMPILER_NAME` - use `CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU"` instead.

Do not use `set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS`. Prefer `target_compiler_options`, `target_link_options`, `target_link_libraries` or `add_compile_options` instead.

Do not write long lines. Split them with newlines as a list.

`set(COMMON_FLAGS` - if they are common, why add them to `_RELEASE` and `_DEBUG` separately? Just `add_compile_options` them.

Comment: I am brand new to all of this so I cannot say thank you enough!! This was so helpful, I'll work on those changes the second I get the chance.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the current error, it appears to be something with how I am linking libraries I think but I can't quite seem to pin it down. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions Remember to create an [MCVE]. Also compile with verbose build `cmake --build <buididr> --verbose` and post/inspect the compiler line. I suspect `libs:static` - anyway, _debug_ that manual way - remove lines until you are left with the minimal [MCVE], and then with minimum you'll know what's wrong... The same way you could have found `-c` - by removing stuff.